# How to add horizontal dodge to labels in a ggplot2 bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I am trying to add labels to a rather simple bar chart (i.e., geom_bar).  `position_dodge()` within `geom_text()` corrects the vertical spacing of the labels, but not the horizontal spacing.  How can I get `ggplot2` to disperse my labels above the bars properly?

```
library(tidyr)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

data = read.table('temp.dat', header=T)

data <- gather(data, SOA, RT, X0:X1000)

data$ResponseCondition = as.factor(data$ResponseCondition)
levels(data$SOA) = c(0,250,500,1000)
data$SOA = as.numeric(as.character(data$SOA))

p = ggplot(data, aes(y=RT, x=SOA, fill=ResponseCondition, ymax=RT*1.05))
p = p + geom_bar(stat='identity', position=position_dodge())
p = p + geom_text(aes(label=RT), position=position_dodge())

p = p + scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,250,500,1000))

p = p + ylab('Response Time (ms)')
p = p + xlab('Precue Interval (ms)')
p = p + theme_bw()
p = p + scale_fill_grey(start = 0.1, end = .9, name='Response condition')

p = p + theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.30, size=10),
    axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1.50, size=10),
    text = element_text(size=10),
    legend.justification=c(1,1), legend.position=c(1,1),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(.5, 4), 'cm'))

ggsave('temp.png', width=10, height=7.5)
```

Here is the bar chart:

[image: Bar chart]

Here are the contents of `temp.dat` needed to make this a fully working example:

```
ResponseCondition 0    250  500  1000
               28 1254 1056  901  864
               46 1306 1063  889  772
               64 1171  939  786  682
               82 1205  948  821  731
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the main reason why they are not properly dispersed is that the SOA is not a factor variable, you should keep it a factor. Further, if you skip scale_x_continuous, your code should work. This is how I did it with minor changes. You can adjust the vertical distance (vjust) and the colour the way you like:

```
library(tidyr)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

data = read.table('temp.dat', header=T)
data <- gather(data, SOA, RT, X0:X1000)
data$ResponseCondition = as.factor(data$ResponseCondition)
levels(data$SOA) = c(0,250,500,1000)
# data$SOA = as.numeric(as.character(data$SOA))

p = ggplot(data, aes(y=RT, x=SOA, fill=ResponseCondition, ymax=RT*1.05))
p = p + geom_bar(stat='identity', position=position_dodge())
p = p + geom_text(aes(label=RT), colour="purple", vjust=1.5, position=position_dodge(0.9), size=4)

# p = p + scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,250,500,1000))

p = p + ylab('Response Time (ms)')
p = p + xlab('Precue Interval (ms)')
p = p + theme_bw()
p = p + scale_fill_grey(start = 0.1, end = .9, name='Response condition')

p = p + theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.30, size=10),
    axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1.50, size=10),
    text = element_text(size=10),
    legend.justification=c(1,1), legend.position=c(1,1),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(.5, 4), 'cm'))

ggsave('temp.png', width=10, height=7.5)
```

Comment: That fixed it, and will work for now, thank you!  I am curious, though: Do you know how to fix the problem while maintaining a continuous scale?  I know it's unusually to use a continuous scale on the x-axis for a bar chart, but sometimes it can be helpful for expository.

Comment: Sorry, until now I was not able to find a way that allows me using a continuous scale on a categorical x-variable without having problems with labels in such cases. If you happen to come up with a trick, please do post it here!